# Documentation from several github repositories into a static site

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, documentation, vuepress, docsify

I need to some help to identify the correct solution that would help me create a seamless documentation for my friends.
We have several repositories in which a doc folder with several .MD files are going to be placed

```
Repo1
|- Readme.MD
|-docs
  |- Installation.MD
  |- Usage.MD

Repo2
|- Readme.MD
|-docs
  |- Installation.MD
  |- Usage.MD

Repo3
|- Readme.MD
|-docs
  |- Installation.MD
  |- Usage.MD
```

We would like to use something like vuepress to generate a static site.
If there is any tool/framework which can easily solve this issue. I would be grateful

Thanks a lot for any response,we will definitely put below what we have done

Comment: if the md files are in the project i recommend using [nuxt content](https://content.nuxtjs.org/)

Comment: Thanks, will look into it. All the MD files are not in the same project

Comment: To combine several markdown repositories into one documentation site I would recommend [Foliant](https://foliant-docs.github.io/docs). Check the [include](https://foliant-docs.github.io/docs/preprocessors/includes/) preprocessor to get more info on how to achieve this.

Comment: Tested both nuxt and Foliant. Both are site generator for my documentation. vuepress does the same. I am more looking into something that looks into several github accounts and gets the MD files associated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this using [MkDocs](https://www.mkdocs.org/) as your static site generator and the [multirepo plugin](https://github.com/jdoiro3/mkdocs-multirepo-plugin). Below are the steps to get it all setup. I assume you have Python installed and you created a Python [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html).

1. `python -m pip install git+https://github.com/jdoiro3/mkdocs-multirepo-plugin`
2. `mkdocs new my-project`
3. `cd my-project`
4. Add the below to your newly created `mkdocs.yml`. This will configure the plugin.

```yaml
plugins:
  - multirepo:
      repos:
        - section: Repo1
          import_url: {Repo1 url}
        - section: Repo2
          import_url: {Repo2 url}
        - section: Repo3
          import_url: {Repo3 url}
```

Now, you can run `mkdocs serve` or `mkdocs build`, which will build a static site with all the documentation in one site.

Comment: how do I set the credentials for the acess to the repositories?
it works also for any git repository (e.g. an onpremise gitlab)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea,

1. Initialize a repository, lets call it `TheRepo`
2. Add all depending repos (in our case `Repo1`, `Repo2`, `Repo3`) as [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) to `TheRepo`

Now we have everything from `Repo1`, `Repo2` and `Repo3` into `TheRepo`, which I assume might be undesirable for a documentation website.

3. Create a bash script (using `find`, `grep`, `rm` or similar bash charm) to retain the desired `*.md` files and remove the undesirable source files. Here is a sample on how-to:

```sh
// remove everything else that is not markdown file
find . -type f ! -name '*.md' -delete
```

4. Initialize [vuepress](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/getting-started.html) at `TheRepo`'s root and let vuepress generate cosolidated documentation.

If you do a good job at step 3. you can have a seperate [section/classification](https://vuepress-plugin-blog.ulivz.com/guide/getting-started.html#document-classifier) for each individual dependency Repo in the resulting documentation.

To refresh the contents, simple use `git submodule update` to update documentation and then chain it with script created in step3 as to automate the refresh process.

```sh
git submodule update && ./remove-undesirable-files.sh
```